# Facebook iOS App Invites are being sent but users don't receive them

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I created an invite url using [Facebook tool](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host).
Then I created a custom URL Scheme in info.plist. Same as used in invite url.
Next, I'm calling:

```
let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent()

content.appLinkURL = URL(string: "https://1234")
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = URL(string: "http://myurl/fb-invite.png")

FBSDKAppInviteDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
```

As a result I get a proper invite page -> select friends -> send an invite -> get a UI indication that all went successfully.
But none of the recipients gets the invite.
None of the recipients ever installed or logged into the app.
Facebook admin panel says that the app is public.
Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: your link is saying "Reminder: Graph API v2.2 is no longer available as of March 27, 2017. For more details see the changelog" https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: maybe check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/ to see if this is affecting your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appeared to be a known issue on Facebook side. You can track the status here:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262511517540133/?hc_location=ufi

Answer (score 2):

Facebook shows notification only to test users added in the Facebook dashboard (if your app is not published).

Also the invite notification is only sent if the user does not have the app already installed. Invite notifications also don't show up on web (only on Facebook mobile app)

Finally make sure you are also checking for the invite under the "App invitation" section in FB app, sometimes the invites are hidden there.

Comment: Yep, I know about these nuances, but none is the case. It's an issue on Facebook side. Check my answer above - there you can find a link to FB issue tracker.